# DropDown AutoPostBack not working on IIS

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, dropdown, iis-8

In my web application ,  I have a drop-down list when the page loads It works right but when I select item of drop-down list after AutoPostBack  i get this error **"Error Code 11001: Host not found "** , Its AutoPostBack property is set to True.

This works fine when running the website in the development server on local host but when it is run from the browser from IIS I get this error .

I use windows server 2012 and IIS 8

my aspx code

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/default.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Async="true" CodeBehind="Supp_Ek.aspx.cs" Inherits="sapcodashboard100.Supp_Ek" %>

<asp:DropDownList ID="cmbSupp" runat="server" CssClass="cmd" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbSupp_SelectedIndexChanged"  AutoPostBack="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="supplier name">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and my CS code

```
    DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
    ReadData rd = new ReadData();
    DataTable dtsupp = new DataTable();
    DataTable dtpart = new DataTable(); 

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GetData();
        }
    }
    private void GetData()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        ds = rd.Read("getsupp_EK");
        dtsupp = ds.Tables[0];

        cmbSupp.DataSource = dtsupp;
        cmbSupp.DataTextField = "Fullname";
        cmbSupp.DataValueField = "Id";
        cmbSupp.DataBind();

        string supcode = dtsupp.Rows[0][3].ToString();

        ReadSendData(supcode);
    }
    protected void cmbSupp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    ds = rd.Read("getsupp_EK");
    dtsupp = ds.Tables[0];

    int index = cmbSupp.SelectedIndex;
    string supcode = dtsupp.Rows[index][3].ToString();

    ReadSendData(supcode);
}
```

Comment: Is your url before and after the postback the same?

Comment: Launch your browser Developer Tools by pression F12 and then click on the Network tab. Now, select an option from dropdown and monitor network traffic. Also, please check if you have any client-side event handler registered for onchange event which may be redirecting.

Comment: @SehaxX The url does not change before and after the postback

Comment: @Mohsin Mehmood - i monitor network traffic and i have 3 rows that 2 rows for my page get and post , one row I do not know what it was. i dont have any client-side event handler registered for onchange event

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your network traffic

Comment: @MustafaQarehkhani ok if you notice that on POST request there is server error (500 response). I suggest you put a breakpoint inside `cmbSupp_SelectedIndexChanged`. I noticed this code `ds = rd.Read("getsupp_EK")` so what is `rd`??

Comment: @Mohsin Mehmood -  rd is my class for connected database , This works fine when running the website in Local host. i edit my question.

Comment: Ok on the server in network tab after postback double click on the `POST` request row to see if it shows any additional details related to error.

Comment: I did not find any solution :(